# Unable to load magento site

Tags: magento2

I have installed a magento site but I don't see an index.php file. Please tell me how to fix it.
I have tried many ways on google with no success

Comment: Hi there, have u checked inside from your root directory in this path - pub/index.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the index.php file in the pub directory outside the root, then open the index.php file and change the following line of code:

`require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';`

to

```
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
```

Comment: ok, it work. Thanks